# Find the value ${a_{10}}^2+4a_{9}-a_9a_{11}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $a_0=3$ and $a_1=7$ and $a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+6a_n=2$ for all $n$. What's the value of
$${(a_{10})}^2+4a_{9}-a_9a_{11}$$

---

I have successfully solved the recursion and obtained the explicit formula $a_n=2\times 3^n+1$. However, I am currently facing challenges in progressing further.

Comment: At this point it's just algebra. Compute $a_{9}, a_{10}, a_{11}$ and then substitute them into the formula and carry out the computation. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The test indicates that the correct solution is $7$; however, I am unable to reach this result.

Comment: Is there a fast way to solve this? In the test there is only 1 minute to solve this

Comment: Try substituting $x=3^9$ and simplifying the subsequent algebraic expression. BTW I think you mean $-5a_{\color{red}{n+1}}$.

Comment: @user170231 yep I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \left( 
\begin{array}{cccccc} 
n & 3^n & a_n & a_n^2 - a_{n+1}  a_{n-1} & 4 a_{n-1} & add \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 &  &  &  \\ 
1 & 3 & 7 & -8 &  12 & 4 \\ 
2 & 9 & 19 & -24 & 28 & 4 \\ 
3 & 27 & 55 &  &  &  \\
4 & 81 & 163 &  &  &  \\
5 & 243 & 487 &  &  &  \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
You should fill this  table in. the thing with the square, $7^2 - 19 \cdot 3 = 49 - 57 =-8.$  Next $ 19^2 - 55 \cdot 7 = 361 - 385 = -24.$
So, what is $55^2 - 163 \cdot 19 \; ? \; \;  $

the predictable thing is that  $a_n^2 - a_{n+1} a_{n-1}  $
is fairly simple because of cancellation. Just write it out,
$$   a_{n+1} a_{n-1}   - a_n^2  = 8 \cdot 3^{n-1} $$
so
$$     a_n^2 - a_{n+1} a_{n-1}   = -8 \cdot 3^{n-1} $$   and
$$ a_{n-1}  = 1 + 2 \cdot 3^{n-1}.$$

Multiply by $4$   and add, you get $4.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=3^9$ and simplify, which I think can reasonably be done within a minute if one is familiar with binomial expansions or the [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) for the coefficients.

$$\begin{align*}
A &= a_{10}^2 + 4a_9 - a_9 a_{11} \\
&= \left(2\cdot3x + 1\right)^2 + 4\left(2x + 1\right) - \left(2x + 1\right) \left(2\cdot9x + 1\right) \\
&= 36 \left(x + \frac16\right)^2 + 8\left(x + \frac12\right) - 36\left(x + \frac12\right) \left(x + \frac1{18}\right) \\
&\,\,\vdots
\end{align*}$$

but note that $A\neq7$.